# Bringing P type and N type semiconductors together in vacuum

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

Consider the case where a P-type semiconductor and an N-type semiconductor are placed in perfect vacuum.  Now, the two junctions are brought together.

1. In the time immediately after they are brought in contact (say the first 1 micro seconds after they are brought in contact), will I detect a current through the device if the P and N sides are connected with a piece of conducting wire?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, what happens if I do not have any sort of external circuit? Is the depletion region not formed?

Comment: You have to realize that in your experiment you have four surfaces involved in two interfacing situations. The conductor and the semiconductor will most likely form a rectifying Shottky junction. There will be a transient charge transfer at those two interfaces but the charge transfer you would expect from n to p semiconductor could not take place because of the barriers created. In short, the system you propose is much more complicated than two semiconductors alone.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, No, you won't detect any current...Second of all, a junction isn't formed just by bringing two semiconductors together in contact. It is a process where the two materials are heated up forming a crystal structure and thus its conductive properties

Why won't you detect any current? That's an experimental fact, what is maybe confusing you is the fact that there is no NET current in the device, but there is an inner current of 4 components which is not zero, and they cancel each other resulting no net current.

A description of the current is as follows:
(Based on the book Solid State Electronic Devices pages 195-196 )

> When Putting two materials together, forming a P-N junction, we have
> four components to participate in the flow. We expect diffusion of
> carriers to take place, holes diffuse from the p side into the n side,
> and electrons diffuse from n to p, And we have drift current to oppose
> them. Since we know that no net current can flow across the junction
> at equilibrium, the current due to the drift of carriers in the ℰ
> field must exactly cancel the diffusion current. Furthermore, since
> there can be no net buildup  of electrons or holes on either side as a
> function of time, the drift and diffusion currents must cancel for
> each type of carrier.

Comment: 1) Why wont you detect any current? 
2) I know how a junction is formed. I am not looking for an answer on the fabrication process.

Comment: _"Why won't you detect any current? That's an experimental fact"_ No it isn't.

Comment: In that book they base all of their arguments on that fact, so what is it?